# Value of CDF at infinity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had a question, given a continuous CDF F, is $F(+\infty)$ essentially equal to 1?

Comment: By [(the immediate consequences of the) definition of a CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties), $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) =1$.

Comment: Great. Just for closure and future readers, I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [(the immediate consequences of the) definition of a CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties), $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) =1$.